# Принудительное занесение данных о внешних сборках в манифест

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest

Есть ли возможность указать сборке (*.dll) занести в свой манифест данные о другой сборке (.extern assembly), прикрепленной через ссылки и расположенной в выходном каталоге (функция копировать локально), но не использующейся в коде в файлах *.cs?
Есть решение делать заглушки в коде, якобы пространства имён используются, но это костыль какой-то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам удалось задать вопрос так, что я его не понял. Зачем оно вам?